# Python errors show up with Rust Cargo

Tags: python, rust-cargo

When I try run a library example with Cargo for some reason a Python error comes up. I have no idea why or how this is happening, does anyone think they might know how to fix this?

```
cargo run --example lib_example
```

```
module 'json' has no attribute 'JSONDecodeError'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 117, in get_snaps
    snaps = json.loads(output)
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 23, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 95, in main
    if not cnf.advise(args[0], options.ignore_installed) and not options.no_failure_msg:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 364, in advise
    snaps, mispell_snaps = self.get_snaps(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 118, in get_snaps
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'JSONDecodeError'
```

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: @hack3r_0m I'm not using python for any python in this Rust library or example, but when I do use python I use Python 3.

Comment: Can you verify you have cargo installed correctly? (Like what is the output of `which cargo`?)

Comment: ``which cargo`` ``/home/nathan/.cargo/bin/cargo``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but running `which` for cargo then restarting somehow fixed it.

```
which cargo
sudo reboot
```

Comment: `which` wouldn't have changed anything, but I guess a reboot might have done something.

Comment: If you have a terminal open and install something that changes `$PATH`, that open terminal is not aware of the change. `which` is probably an different program, which gets the new `$PATH` and had you opened another terminal or started a new shell in another way, that shell would run cargo just fine as well without rebooting.